# How can I create this RegEx?

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx for a text input that has the following rules:

1. Valid values should be like H123, 0945, PUBG
2. Only allow 4 characters
3. Don't allow 0000 specifically or anything like "solo" (ie. Solo, SOLO, solo, etc)

Can anyone help?

Comment: `/^(?!0{4}|solo).{4}$/i`

Comment: Absolutely nothing in this question that would necessitate the jQuery Validate plugin tag.  Edited.   Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Sparky - I'm using jquery validate, I didn't add the part that related to that before I created the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!SOLO)(?!0000)[\dA-Z]{4}$
```

or

```
^(?!SOLO|0000)[\dA-Z]{4}$
```

Use the i flag for case insensitivity.

Comment: You can test it here, https://regex101.com, do not forget the i option near the little flag in the regex input box.

Comment: That website also explains very nicely how/why it works.

Comment: Hmm, no matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/gi44D4/1/) - though I imagine that's the ^ doing that. Why isn't at least the first line matching? How can it be modified to work and return four matches in this example? (H123, 0945, PUBG and H851)

Comment: @djbyter enable multi line in flags.

Comment: Glad we could help.

Comment: `^(?![sS][oO][lL][oO]|0000)[\dA-Za-z]{4}`  doesn't require `i` option.